# converting yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, date, datetime, time-series

I received timestamp datasets which are in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ms`. I want to convert into `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format. Is there any way to select only in this format using matlab?

For example:

```
2012-08-01 00:10:00.0
```

should be:

```
2012-08-01 00:10:00
```

Please note that the millisecond values are all zero.

Comment: Do you have this stored as a string?

Comment: It is in cell array format

Comment: What about each time stamp? Is it a cell array of strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the input and output format are the same except for the milliseconds, don't use date functions, but simple string operations:

```
% example dates
C = {'2012-08-01 00:10:00.0'
     '2013-08-02 00:11:11.0'
     '2014-08-03 00:12:22.0'
     '2015-08-04 00:13:33.0'
     '2016-08-05 00:14:44.0'};

% method 1
D = cellfun(@(x)x(1:end-2), C, 'UniformOutput', false);

% method 2 (same, but no cellfun)
D = char(C);
D = cellstr(D(:,1:end-2));

% method 3
D = regexp(C, '[^\.]*', 'match', 'once');

% method 4
D = regexprep(C, '\..*$', '');
```

Comment: Thanks its quite simple. can you help me related question link given below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364396/adding-nan-to-missing-timestamp-and-filtration-of-data-using-matlab   although solution I got my solution but its very lengthy and complex. Can you tell me to solve this problem in more simpler approach ?.

Answer (score 4):

The general way would be to use `datestr` to convert it to your desired format.

```
dates = {'2012-08-01 00:10:00.1';
         '2012-08-01 00:10:00.1'};

new = datestr(dates, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
%   2012-08-01 00:10:00
%   2012-08-01 00:10:00
```

Another approach would be that since all of your milliseconds are going to be zero (therefore you don't have to worry about rounding) you can just use a regular expression to remove the milliseconds component (anything after the decimal point)

```
new = regexprep(dates, '\..*', '')
```

This is likely going to be more performant as you don't need to perform the intermediate step of converting to either a `datetime` object or a date number.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you need this data in datetime objects anyway then i would do something like this:

```
inp = {'2012-08-01 00:10:00.0'; '2012-08-02 04:10:00.0'}; % Some datestrins
t = datetime(inp,'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.0'); % Convert to datetimes
datestr(t, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS') % convert back to strings
```

For the [input](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_formatOut) & [output](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#inputarg_infmt) formatter see the documentation. I assume that the last part is always zero.